# EF6: Include over nested TPH structure in SQL Server

Tags: c#, eager-loading

Hello everybody and a happy new 2017,

I have the following table-/object structure.

```
[Table("Table1")]
public class Table1
{
    [Key]
    public long Table1Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Table2> ItemsOfTable2 { get; set; }
}

[Table("Table2")]
public class Table2
{
    [Key]
    public long Table2Id { get; set; }

    public long Table1Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Table1Id")]
    public virtual Table1 Table1Object { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Table3Base> ItemsOfTable3 { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual ICollection<Table3Red> RedItems
    {
        get { return this.ItemsOfTable3.OfType<Table3Red>().ToList(); }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual ICollection<Table3Blue> BlueItems
    {
        get { return this.ItemsOfTable3.OfType<Table3Blue>().ToList(); }
    }
}

[Table("Table3Base")]
public abstract class Table3Base
{
    [Key]
    public long Table3Id { get; set; }

    public long Table2Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Table2Id")]
    public virtual Table2 Table2Object { get; set; }
}

public class Table3Red : Table3Base
{
    public string SpecialPropertyForRed { get; set; }
}

public class Table3Blue : Table3Base
{
    public int SpecialPropertyForBlue { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Table4> ItemsOfTable4 { get; set; }
}

[Table("Table4")]
public class Table4
{
    [Key]
    public long Table4Id { get; set; }

    public long Table3Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Table3Id")]
    public virtual Table3Blue Table3BlueObject { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual IDbSet<Table1> Table1DbSet { get; set; }
    public virtual IDbSet<Table2> Table2DbSet { get; set; }
    public virtual IDbSet<Table3Red> Table3RedDbSet { get; set; }
    public virtual IDbSet<Table3Blue> Table3BlueDbSet { get; set; }
    public virtual IDbSet<Table4> Table4DbSet { get; set; }
}
```

So, in the middle of this "tree", there is a TPH structure (classes Table3Base, Table3Red, Table3Blue stored in database table "Table3Base"). And we only have IDbSets for Table3Red and Table3Blue, not for Table3Base. Every object has a collection navigation property of the next table objects.

Class Table3Blue has another collection navigation property to items of Table4 objects.

As further (but hopefully irrelevant) information: The default discriminator is mapped to an internal enum:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

    // TPH: Map Standard-Discriminator to Enum
    modelBuilder.Entity<Table3Base>()
        .Map<Table3Red>(m => m.Requires("Typ").HasValue((int)Table3TypEnum.Red))
        .Map<Table3Blue>(m => m.Requires("Typ").HasValue((int)Table3TypEnum.Blue));
}
```

Due to performance issues (loading every single record one by one is very slow; Lazy Loading is active), we want to read this structure from Table1 to Table4 via include like this:

```
var table1Records = this.m_Context.Table1DbSet
    .Include(t => t.ItemsOfTable2)
    .Include(t => t.ItemsOfTable2.Select(t2 => t2.ItemsOfTable3))
    .Include(t => t.ItemsOfTable2.Select(t2 => t2.ItemsOfTable3.OfType<Table3Blue>().Select(t3 => t3.ItemsOfTable4)))
    .ToList();
```

The first and the second include seem to work, but the third include throws an Argument exception "The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
Parametername: path".

What am I doing wrong? How do I include Table4-objects on my way to the database?

Kind regards, Mate

Comment: Looks like you're asking for the not-supported... https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/594289/in-entity-framework-there-should-be-a-way-to-eager-load-include-navigation-properties-of-a-derived-class

Answer (score 0):

This is our workaround. I doubt this is the best solution, so better ways are highly appreciated...

Table3Base gets the collection navigation property to Table4 as a virtual property.

Table3Red (the object without Table4-objects) overrides this property with a getter returning an empty list of Table4 objects and no setter.

Therefore, we can cascade our Include down to Table4 without any type checks. There are no unnecessary records in our PTH database table "Table3Base". So everything is fine, except the clumsy definition of Table3Red with an unused navigation property. :-(

BTW: Include with a long path includes all objects along this path, so the explicit ".Include(A).Include(A.B).Include(A.B.C)" is not necessary; ".Include(A.B.C)" will do the same. The iterating .Include in the code sample is for clarity.

HTH, Mate